# How to handle DOM events in an embedded document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page embedded inside another page. Now I would like to make visible a div in the parent document, by clicking on a link in the embedded document. I know how to make a div visible (I'm using jQuery), but how do I check if somebody clicked on a link in an embedded document?

I have a situation like this:

index.html

```
<div id="box1">Text</div> 

<div id="wBox1">
  <a href="#" class="hideLink">[X]</a>
  <object id="objPage" name="foo" type="text/html" data="box.html"></object>
</div> 

<div id="wProdBox1">
  <a href="#" class="hideLink">[X]</a>
  <object id="objPage2" name="foo" type="text/html" data="box1.html"></object>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#box1").click(function () { 
    $("#wBox1").show("slow"); 
    $("body").addClass("scroll"); 
  }); 

  $("#product1").click(function () { 
   $("#wProdBox1").show("slow"); 
   $("body").addClass("scroll"); 
  }); 
</script>
```

And in box.html

```
<div id="product1">Text box</div>
```

So I need to open a div in index.html by clicking on div id=product1 in box.html.

Comment: How are pages related? Are they parent/child, or perhaps sibling frames?

Comment: Did one of the windows open the other using JavaScript?

Comment: so now should be more clearly

Comment: I've updated my answer below to better address your actual situation, now that I can see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interaction between separate browser windows is quite different from interaction between a document and its embedded documents.  As such [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9474537/3) won't be much help.  I've updated my answer below to apply to your situation.  I've also updated your question title to better reflect what you are trying to do.

The following techniques will work to bind a click event in an embedded document:

Bind from the embedded document, and reference the parent document with `top.document`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#product1").click(function () {
        $("#wProdBox1", top.document).show("slow");
    });
});
```

Or, bind from the parent document, and reference the embedded document with `document.foo.contentDocument`:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document.foo.contentDocument).ready(function () {
        $("#product1", document.foo.contentDocument).click(function () {
            $("#wProdBox1").show("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

**But...** That's the happy path and works in modern browsers.  Sadly, we have some difficulties to work out in order to support IE8 and IE7:

1. The second technique doesn't work in IE7 because it doesn't support `contentDocument`.
2. The first technique doesn't work in IE8 and IE7 because the embedded document thinks it is the top window.  Ie, `window.top === window`.

To fix issue 1, it's not too bad.  If `document.foo.contentDocument` doesn't exist, we use `document.foo.parentWindow.document`:

```
var boxDoc = document.foo.contentDocument || document.foo.parentWindow.document;
$(boxDoc).ready(function ()
{
    $("#product1", boxDoc).click(function (e)
    {
        $("#wProdBox1").show("slow");
    });
});
```

To fix issue 2, We need to add some code to the parent document to tell the embedded document about the parent window.

```
boxDoc.parentWindow.parentDocument = document;
```

**But...** Chrome and FireFox don't support `parentWindow`.  To get the document's window, you have to use `defaultView`, and IE7 doesn't support `defaultView`.  So, our code becomes:

```
var boxWin = boxDoc.defaultView || boxDoc.parentWindow;
boxWin.parentDocument = document;
```

Then, we have to reference `parentDocument` in the embedded document:

```
$("#wProdBox1", parentDocument).toggle();
```

Here's a [working cross-browser demo](http://jumpingfishes.com/embeddedDocument/) that uses both techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using frames within one browser window and the pages have the same origin (they are from the same domain), then you use something like this:

$(window.top.frames['otherframe']).find("#someId").hide();

If you have two completely different browser window then you cannot do this. You'll need to do something via the server.

Answer (score 0):

They need to be in the same domain, due to the same-origin-policy.

If the pages are `<[i]frame>`d, you can access the other page's variables and functions directly. The same is possible, when one of the windows was opened with js by

```
var otherWindow = window.open(...);
otherWindow.onload = function() {
    otherWindow.showDivs(); // as declared in a script on the other page
    orDoSomethingWith(otherWindow.document);
};
```

If the two pages are not references directly from each other, you might use `window.postMessage`.